# Getting a blank cmd prompt on running a bat file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, batch-file, child-process

I am trying to run a .bat file by passing arguments to it in nodejs. However, I get an empty command prompt. How to get the command pasted on the path.

code -

**server.js**

```
var bat = require.resolve('E:/API_Gateway_through_Swagger/New_Project/aws-bat-file-3.bat');
var num = "123"
var state_desc = "abc";

var ls = spawn(bat, [num, state_desc  ]);

ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

ls.on('exit', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

Bat file  -

**aws-bat-file-3.bat**

```
echo off
echo "Batch Started"
set arg1=%1
set arg2=%2

START "Task Options"  cmd.exe /b " cd C:\Users\myfolder &  aws apigateway create deployment  --rest-api-id  %arg1%  --stage-name dev  --stage-description  %arg2%"
```

**output img file is -**

[image: cmd-prompt]

Comment: To pass commands to `cmd.exe`, add the commands after `/c`. View `cmd /?` for help. At the moment, cmd.exe is being opened and does not know what commands to run so is waiting for input. `start` has a `/d` argument for startup directory and that might be better than use of `cd` in the command passed to cmd.exe.

Answer (score 1):

NodeJS documented the problem of spawning batch files on Windows thoroughly [in this section](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_spawning_bat_and_cmd_files_on_windows).

Excerpt:

> When running on Windows, .bat and .cmd files can be invoked using child_process.spawn() with the shell option set, with child_process.exec(), or by spawning cmd.exe and passing the .bat or .cmd file as an argument (which is what the shell option and child_process.exec() do).
>
> ```
> const bat = spawn('"my script.cmd"', ['a', 'b'], { shell: true });
> ```

Comment: Sorry @SOFe  writing -->var ls = spawn(bat, [num, state_desc  ]), {shell: true};   made no difference

Comment: Have you checked if your `bat` value points to the correct path?